# How to change page order of a PDF file

Tags: pdf, text-editing

I am looking for an fast online/offline free solution to change the page order of a PDF file, such as changing the 5th page of a PDF with 3rd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the free [PDFill PDF Tools](http://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html)

[image]

Comment: link does not work well...need to change .HTML to .html  ...

Comment: @NT: Edited as you requested, although AFAIK it shouldn't matter.

Comment: No freeware. Watermark will be added.

Comment: @BenCes: The linked page says: "No watermarks! No pop-up ads! FREE for personal or commercial use! FREE distribution!".

Comment: Test it by yourself and check the watermarks.

Answer (score 10):

If you use or have access to a Mac:

- Open the pdf with Preview.
- Select View -> Contact Sheet or View -> Thumbnails
- Drag the pages into the order you want them in.
- Save the file.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way?  Print the original PDF, choosing either Cute PDF Writer or Adobe PDF from the print dialogue screen. Under "Print Range", simply type all of the pages in the order you want them printed (eg. "1,2,5,4,3,6,7,8).  The file will prompt you to save to a location.  The saved PDF will be with pages in the new order.

Comment: Can you add links to the software you specified and give a description of the software in question?

Comment: http://www.cutepdf.com/

Comment: You can do this with any pdfprinter e.g. doPdf, thanks Larry, very clever solution!

Comment: I used Adobe Reader to print to "Microsoft Print to PDF" with a different page order, and it worked, but the resulting file is 40% larger.  That doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 4):

[pdftk](http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/) can be used to perform various operations on a PDF file.

Answer (score 2):

For changing the page ordering, there's a very simple online tool called [PDFHammer](http://www.pdfhammer.com/startproject.php) that should do the trick.

If you happen to be on a Mac, Preview can be used for more advanced editing of PDFs, including annotating pages, adding extra images as well as rearranging and deleting pages.

Comment: The online tool has been removed. Should we down-vote answers that were once correct, but no longer.

Comment: Too bad, that tool was amazing.

Answer (score 1):

[PDFSAM](http://www.pdfsam.org/) (PDF Split and Merge) is a free open-source tool that can split PDF documents out to individual pages and then remerge them in whatever order you like.  I've used it previously and it works great.  I *think* it requires the Java runtime which is installed on practically every machine these days so generally it "just works".

Comment: "Java runtime which is installed on practically every machine these days" - not true at all!

Comment: Okay, To clarify: I wouldn't touch Java with a barge pole even if you paid me (well, maybe if you paid me a lot) but there are still a lot of websites and some programs that require Java, and while I admit it also isn't installed by default it is incredibly easy to visit J. Random Website and a few clicks later have Java installed.  I would expect quite a few Linux distros to have it by default (to make life easier) and from what I've read MacOS X comes with Apple(C) Java preinstalled too.  You want me to change it to read "is *available* on practically every machine"?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to re-order the pages of a PDF document on Windows then take a look at [Infix PDF Editor from Iceni...](http://www.pdfediting.com/)

To re-order pages using Infix, simply open your document and then from the menu select 'Document > Pages > Re-order...'

A user-friendly dialog will pop up enabling you to specify a range of pages to move and a target destination. No messing around with command line stuff!

The free version of Infix will apply a small watermark to the footer of saved documents however you'll find this can be removed fairly easily, and there's no trial period expiry.